# Already clicked check box is unchecked while scrolling the list in android

Tags: android

In my app i have a contact list ...By clicking the check box i can add the contacts...While updating the contact, I am getting the already checked check box values from data base to show the already clicked check box to user...So i am getting that eventMO from database...While scrolling the list check became unchecked then next time it is checked...Like this it creating a problem...

This is my code.Please help me to find out the solution

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            // Create a new row view
            if (convertView == null) {

                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // Find the child views.
                holder.userNameTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.mobileNumTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
                holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

                // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have
                // to
                // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            //To reuse already existing rows
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                EventMO eventMO2 = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMO");
                if (eventMO2 != null) {
                    if (userMOs.size() >= eventUserRelationMOs.size()) {
                        if (position <= eventUserRelationMOs.size() - 1) {
                            List<EventUserRelationMO> eventUserRelationMOs = eventMO2.getEventUserRelationBOs();
                            int isInvited = eventUserRelationMOs.get(position).getIsInvited();

                            if (isInvited == 1) {
                                holder.cb.performClick();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            holder.cb.setTag(userMOs.get(position));
            holder.userNameTxtV.setText(userMOs.get(position).getUserName());
            holder.mobileNumTxtV.setText(userMOs.get(position).getMobileNumber());
            holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
                    UserMO userMO = (UserMO) checkBox.getTag();
                    userMO.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());
                }
            });
            EventMO eventMO2 = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMO");
            if (eventMO2 != null) {
                if (userMOs.size() >= eventUserRelationMOs.size()) {
                    if (position <= eventUserRelationMOs.size() - 1) {
                        List<EventUserRelationMO> eventUserRelationMOs = eventMO2.getEventUserRelationBOs();
                        int isInvited = eventUserRelationMOs.get(position).getIsInvited();

                        if (isInvited == 1) {
                            holder.cb.performClick();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            holder.cb.setChecked(userMOs.get(position).isSelected());
            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call

```
    holder.cb.setOnClickListener(null);
```

after

```
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    EventMO eventMO2 = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMO");
```

before

```
    if (eventMO2 != null) {
```

in your "else" block.

other way is replace this part :

```
if (isInvited == 1) {
    holder.cb.performClick();
}
```

with this:

```
 holder.cb.setChecked(isInvited == 1);
```

Comment: can u please explain me...what is use of the above line

Comment: checkbox may be in checked or unchecked state because it recycled from other listItem. than when you call performClick checkbox just toggle it state to inverse. assume that checkbox recycled with checked state, and isInvited is true -> you call performClick and checkbox becomes unchecked.